# How to handle competing directives from different modules

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have 2 attribute directives (restrict is set to 'A' on both), `dir1` and `dir2` that are defined in two different modules. In one app (that includes both these modules), we have an element where one of these 2 directives could get added. We currently set things up so that `dir1` is the default for this element, but we want a way to have `dir2` "override" this directive.

The element we want to do this with is part the template of another directive, `parentDir`, so my first thought was adding some functionality to the `compile` function for `parentDir`. The template for `parentDir` would have in it `<div class="myElement" dir1="{{data}}"></div>` and then the compile function would look something like this:

```
function(tElement, tAttrs) {
    if ("true" == tAttrs.useDir2)
    {
        var myElement = tElement.find("div.myElement");
        myElement.removeAttr("dir1");
        myElement.attr("dir2", "{{data}}");
    }

    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
    // link stuff
    }
}
```

where `useDir2` would be an attribute on the `parentDir` directive. This would work fine, but the value for `useDir2` is an interpolated value, so I wouldn't be looking at the value I want with `tAttrs.useDir2`.

I thought about setting priorities on the 2 directives, but then each directive would have to know the other's priority to make sure they related to each other correctly. You wouldn't want someone to come into one module and change the priority for something else, and break this functionality. Since the two directives are in different modules, I want them to be completely ignorant of each other.

I hope I've explained my problem clearly enough. I'm just not sure how to go about doing this, and think I may be missing some easy way to do this. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a case where **inside the same module**, you would use `dir1` in one element and in other element you would use `dir2`?

Comment: The problem is clear, but the solution is not.  Since `userDir2` needs to be interpolated, I think that means you can only get the interpolated value in the linking function (because you need to interpolate against the scope).  But, directive `dir1` will compile and link before `parentDir`'s link function runs (I think).

Comment: I guess I should have asked in that last comment: does it matter if directive `dir1` runs, but then it gets replaced by `dir2`?  If it doesn't matter, than @CaioToOn's solution should work fine.

Comment: They each add a css class and bind a click event to the element. So, if `dir2` replaced it later, the class and click event would still be there for `dir1` which would be a problem. If I'm understanding @CaioToOn's solution correctly, it would solve this problem, since it's replacing the whole element, right?

Comment: Yes, that is my understanding also.

Comment: If you just want to set a class and a click event handler, why don't you just use a `ng-click` and a `ng-class`?

Comment: Well, there's more going on that prevents me from being able to that. I'll spare the details. I put your solution into place, and it works well enough. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you will need to do something like you proposed. If you need it to be defined in run-time (i.e. by the controller), in your linking function, `$observe` the attribute and then change and recompile the element contents when the value is changed. Something like this:

```js
app.directive('parentDir', function($compile) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
        attr.$observe('parentDir', function(value) {
            var div = angular.element('<div ' + value + '></div>');
            element.find('div').remove();
            element.append(div);
            $compile(div)(scope);
        });
    },
    template: '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="val"/> Use directive 2: ' + 
            '<div></div>'
  };
});
```

I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CaioToOn/4nrkY/).

Naturally, I simplified the parentDir, you might need to cache the original state of the DOM, so you can safely recompile it.

Comment: This is certainly one way of solving the problem, but I'm not sure I like the idea of having to manually compile the element for `dir2`. However, there may not be a better way. I want to see if there are any other suggestions, but if not, we may just have to do it this way.